# How do I write a code to select someone's else another users ID while logged in as another use

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm new to PHP. I am trying to build messaging into a learning project. I know I can set sessions and select the id from the session when i want to query database for myself. 
But, I want to write mysql query to select from where senderId is my id and recieverId is another user. How do I get the other users id simply by clicking on the username.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your website is designed.

Make a hidden input field. When you click others username, then set the value by JQuery

```
<input type="hidden" id="other_user_id" name="other_user_id" value="">
```

and set value by JS

```
document.getElementById('other_user_id').value = other_user_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try this.